# C makefile undefined-reference error

Tags: c, makefile, undefined-reference

I am having slight problems with using makefile in C. Ive been following a tutorial in a textbook, but it doesnt seem to want to work. I have three files, message_hider.c, encrypt.h and encrypt.c. When I create a makefile for these files it returns an error, but when I run each command individually it works just fine. Here are my files.

encrypt.c

```
#include "encrypt.h"

void encrypt(char *message) {
char c;
while (*message) {
*message = *message ^ 31;
message++;
}
}
```

message_hider.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "encrypt.h"

int main() {
char msg[80];
while (fgets(msg, 80, stdin)) {
encrypt(msg);
printf("%s", msg);
}
}
```

encrypt.h

```
void encrypt(char *message);
```

Makefile

```
message_hider: message_hider.o encrypt.o
    gcc message_hider.o encrypt.o -o message_hider
message_hider.o: message_hider.c encrypt.h
    gcc -c message_hider.c
encrypt.o: encrypt.c encrypt.h
    gcc -c encrypt.c
```

Error message

```
$ make message_hider
cc   message_hider.o   -o message_hider
message_hider.o:message_hider.c:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `encrypt'
message_hider.o:message_hider.c:(.text+0x17): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32       against undefined symbol `encrypt'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     message_hider.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: final link    failed: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'message_hider' failed
make: *** [message_hider] Error 1
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to be using your makefile at all. Try replacing the command in the `message_hider` rule (`gcc message_hider.o ...`) with `echo building $@`, and tell us what happens.

Comment: i replaced it and it came up with exactly the same error

Comment: What is the output of `make --version`, and did you make sure you're using tabs and not four spaces in your makefile?

Comment: yeap im using tabs not spaces. It appears 4 spaces in the code above because SO wouldnt let me insert a tab. make version is GNU Make 4.0, Built for x86_64-pc-cygwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ make message_hider
cc   message_hider.o   -o message_hider
```

That is *not* the rule you've specified in your makefile. First off, it appears to be using `cc` rather than `gcc`. Second, there's *no* mention of `encrypt.o` in there which is why your link is failing.

Try to explicitly use the makefile, such as with:

```
make -f Makefile message_hider
```

It may be that it's picking up a different makefile, one that either has different rules or one that simply relies on the default rules like `.c.o`.

---

And, based on your update that:

```
make -f Makefile message_hider
```

gives you:

```
$ make -f Makefile message_hider
make: Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'Makefile'. Stop.
```

that's the error you get when `Makefile` does not actually exist.

So you need to check that it's in the current directory, and named exactly as you expect.

That would explain the use of default rules as mentioned earlier, since your makefile isn't actually being picked up.

Another thing to check, though it's probably moot now that we've seen the error above, is that you're actually running the correct `make` program. Use `which make` to find out where it is (should be `/usr/bin/make` on CygWin) and `make --version` to check the version.

Comment: when i try the command you wrote above it outputs: $ make -f Makefile message_hider
make: Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'Makefile'.  Stop.

Comment: which make outputs /usr/bin/make like you stated and version outputs GNU Make 4.0, Built for x86_64-pc-cygwin

Comment: @jeebz88, that's the error you get when there's _no_ makefile. So either it's not there or it's named incorrectly.

Comment: ahhh i see whats happened. Makefile saved with a .txt extension. when I remove the .txt extension from the file, or add it to the command it works just fine. thanks alot! the tutorial didnt mention anything about this, it just said to make a text file. thanks alot

Comment: @jeebz88, "make a text file" in that context just means make it with a text editor, not that it has to have a ".txt" extension. Anyway, good to have nutted it out.